# Does has_many association attribute setter always persist its value to a database and is it possible to make it not to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, has-many, rails-activerecord

I have the following script which demonstrates me that has_many `roles=` attribute always works in a persistent manner.

My questions are:

1) What is the reason behind this behavior: why has_many attributes are persisted right at the moment when they've been set? Why this difference from regular attributes behavior (`name` in the following script) ?

2) Can I write my custom `roles=` setter so I could use fx `assign_attributes` for a bunch of models attributes (including roles=) without roles association to be persisted? I would appreciate an example if it is possible in Rails > 3.2 ?

Here is the script:

```
gem 'rails', '>=3.2.0' # change as required
gem 'sqlite3'

require 'active_record'
require 'logger'

puts "Active Record #{ActiveRecord::VERSION::STRING}"
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDERR)

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'sqlite3',
  :database => ':memory:'
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :users, :force => true do |t|
    t.string :name
  end

  create_table :user_roles, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer :user_id
    t.integer :role_id
  end

  create_table :roles, :force => true do |t|
    t.string :name
  end
end

# Create the minimal set of models to reproduce the bug
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles
end

class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
end

r = Role.create(:name => 'admin')
u = User.create

# roles= persists its value, name= does not
u.assign_attributes({ :roles => [r], :name => 'Stanislaw' })

# The same behavior is produced by:
# u.attributes=
# u.roles=

puts "name attribute: #{u.name}"
puts "many roles #{u.roles}"

u.reload

puts "name attribute: #{u.name}"
puts "many roles #{u.roles}" # I see admin role and I want to achieve behavior that I would not see it
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Associations are not the same as attributes. For example with a has_many association all you are doing when you assign is setting the foreign key on the belongs_to side.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

p = Post.create
u = User.create
u.posts << p # this line will simply update p.user_id with u.id
```

In your example with the join table assigning a role to a user will create a UserRole record and with the user_id/role_id records set. This happens because you declared the `has_many :through`

As for preventing this behavior, you could use a virtual attribute that stores the unpersisted roles until you save the record, then create the associations.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :unpersisted_roles
  attr_accessible :unpersisted_roles

  after_save :assign_roles

  def assign_roles
    self.roles << @unpersisted_roles if defined(@unpersisted_roles)
  end
end

r = Role.create
u = User.create
u.attributes = {:unpersisted_roles => [r]}
u.save # roles get persisted here
```

This is only a simple example, actual code might need to be more complicated or require diving deeper into AR's interface to get it working without too many side effects.

If you could give some insight as to why your wanting to not persist the association I might be able to suggest a more specific course of action.

**Update**

In reference to [Issue #3](https://github.com/stanislaw/simple_roles/issues/3) with some comments where changes were made.

```
module SimpleRoles
  module Many
    module Persistence
      class << self
        def included base
          base.class_eval %{
            has_many :user_roles
            has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles
            # Add a callback to persist the roles
            after_create :persist_roles
          }
        end
      end

      def roles
        # Apply unpersisted roles in case we want to access them before saving
        super.map(&:name).map(&:to_sym) + (@unpersisted_roles || [])
      end

      def roles= *rolez
        rolez.to_symbols!.flatten!

        # if we're already persisted then go ahead and save
        # otherwise stash them in an ivar array
        if persisted?
          super retrieve_roles(rolez)
        else
          @unpersisted_roles = rolez
        end
      end

      private

      # Our callback method that sets the roles, this will
      # work since persisted? is true when this runs.
      def persist_roles
        self.roles = @unpersisted_roles
      end

      def retrieve_roles rolez
        raise "Not a valid role!" if (rolez - config.valid_roles).size > 0

        rolez.map do |rolle|
          begin
            Role.find_by_name! rolle.to_s
          rescue
            raise "Couldn't find Role for #{rolle}. Maybe you need to re-run migrations?"
          end
        end
      end

      def config
        SimpleRoles::Configuration
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure, I do really want to "not persist". Original problem is here: https://github.com/stanislaw/simple_roles/issues/3. This is rather old project, very probably I need to completely reconsider roles interface there. Remember: I didn't mean to overuse your brain by posting this link, but I will really be thankful for a good advice!

Comment: Ah i see, it's persisting the user in that issue because in order to build the association it needs a user ID which require user to be persisted, therefore rails is persisting it as it would otherwise lose the information. I'll update with a possible solution.

Comment: Quite so! Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: I've accepted your answer. Thanks for a hint on using a virtual attribute to hack on roles= setter.

Answer (score 0):

We struggled as well with this by-design behaviour of persisting on validation. We have a confirm step, before the actual save but after validation. If a user wants to cancel the action or clicks away the confirm modal, we still had the saved changes.

Our solution: use a param for the validation part of update, put the validation within a transaction and raise a rollback if we are not saving.

```
    def update
    @user = User.find_by(key: params[:id])
    User.transaction do
      @user.assign_attributes(user_params)

      if params[:only_validate] == 'true'
        @user.valid?
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      else
        @user.save
      end
    end
    render json: @user
  end
```

Hope it will be helpful for others with same approach.